# ido-find-file how to prevent `In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.` message to show up

Tags: ido, ido-find-file

I keep seeing following at the top of the buffer when I do: `ido-find-file`.

```
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
```

Would it be possible to prevent this message to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled via the variable `completion-show-help`. Set that to `nil` and you won't see that message anymore.

Comment: Can we also hide the `Possible completions are:` message as well?

Comment: There is no user option to turn that off. The function responsible is `display-completion-list`, in minibuffer.el. You might be able to do something with `completion-setup-hook`, but I don't have time just now to investigate.